# How to implement photon matchmaking with session parameter filters?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

The game has several scenaries and parameters for each of them. I set the room parameters via SessionProperties:

```cs
private async Task StartGame() {
    _runner.ProvideInput = true;

    var result = await _runner.StartGame(new StartGameArgs {
        GameMode = GameMode.AutoHostOrClient,
        Address = NetAddress.Any(),
        SessionProperties = new Dictionary<string, SessionProperty> { { "mode", "example0" } }
    });

    if (!result.Ok)
        Debug.LogError($"Failed to Start: {result.ShutdownReason}\n{result.ErrorMessage}");
    }
}
```

When matchmaking, the SessionProperties value, whatever it is, always looks for a complete match. If you leave the value for the desired key empty, this does not mean “any value that comes up”, but rather “only the same empty values”. Having delved into the documentation on their website, I did not find anything that would help me resolve this issue.

The problem itself is that I want to specify several parameters by which I do not want the player to filter the selection. Everything is complicated by the fact that this is a VR game, where the lobby is not a simple menu, but a transition room where you can walk and communicate.

My current solution is to duplicate information about the rooms being created in Firebase and when searching, search not on the Photon network, but on Firebase, and then join the desired session or create a new one.

But no matter how you look at it, it looks like a crutch. Maybe there is a better solution?